# How to get a single value in a textbox from a row group in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have the following table row group:

Name|Percent|
val1|67%    |
val2|33%    |

I want to know if is possible to get the percent of the val1 in a textbox? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe try using the First function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-first-function

Comment: If there's a single value of **val1** in your table, you can use a LOOKUP with an IIF: `=Lookup("val1", Fields!Name.Value, Fields!Percent.Value, "Dataset1")`. I am **ass**u**me**ing that your table has two rows with val1 and val2 as the **Name** column.

Comment: The percent value is calculated using the following ecuation: =Count(Fields!Name.Value) / Count((Fields!Name.Value), "AllReport"). I was try using the Lookup function but its doesn`t work.

Answer (score 0):

Since your percentage is calculated with the rowcount of val1 to the total rows you can use the expression below:

```
= SUM(Iif(Fields!Name.Value = "val1",1,0))/COUNTROWS("AllReport")
```

The sum actually counts the rows with value equal to "val1"